# Select size attribute size not working in Chrome/Safari?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

How to solve problem that select attribute size, like in code:

```
<select size="2">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Default</option>
    <option value="1">select 1</option>
    <option value="2">select 2</option>
    <option value="3">select 3</option>
</select>
```

How can I get it working in Chrome and Safari?

Comment: you are right , oh just forgot it .

Comment: For 2,3,4 the size wont work, but for the rest it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/ddWr2/). Thats strange.

Comment: Yes it helps. And i've less than 15 reputations and not able to make any acceptions.

Answer (score 9):

This is a **[known bug in webkit browsers](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/z4rBqNT3174)**.

The simplest way to get it to work just how you like it in Chrome and Safari would be to manually specify the styling the select itself.

Here is a [**working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgZnF/4/).

```css
select {
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<select size="2">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="1">select 1</option>
  <option value="2">select 2</option>
  <option value="3">select 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is this actually working? It doesn't work on a webkit real device to me. All this does is increase the height of the dropdown instead of showing more elements as the size attribute continues to be ignored. Yet so many plus voted so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Include `height: auto` and it should work.

```
<select size="2" style="height: auto">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Default</option>
    <option value="1">select 1</option>
    <option value="2">select 2</option>
    <option value="3">select 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `style="height: auto"` does not help for ios `12.5.7` on iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1):

I use the size attribute in the HTML for "other" browsers and then specify webkit appearance in CSS. Other types of menu list options are available, textfield is not the only one. And you may need to mess with height based on font size. This makes it look about the same on all browsers.

**CSS**

```
select{
  -webkit-appearance: menulist-textfield;
  height: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Is this actually working on real devices? It is not working for me as the size attribute continues to be ignored.

Comment: this is old thread but still I want to add that it does not work in mobile browsers

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by adding the "multiple" option to the select tag.

Comment: No, multipe attribute is something entirely different.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Answer (score -5):

Try using the css property `width` of the select tag :

```
select {
  width:value px;
}
```

Comment: select {width:24px;} and size=2 are two differrent thins. Size make such as there: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OSBo9.png