# How can I get the 'size' attribute to work in Mobile-Chrome?

Tags: html, forms, mobile-chrome

My Question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15760089/109941), except that it pertains to **Mobile** Chome.

---

Consider the [following jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgZnF/4/).

```
<select size="2">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Default</option>
    <option value="1">select 1</option>
    <option value="2">select 2</option>
    <option value="3">select 3</option>
</select>
```

- On **Desktop** Chrome, it correctly displays **two** options in the dropdown.
- But on **Mobile** Chrome, it shows only **one**.

---

My Question:

- How can I get the 'size' attribute to work in Mobile-Chrome?

Comment: Can you just set the height manually as suggested in an answer to the question you linked to? It may be that Mobile Chrome has the same bug and this is the only solution.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work.