# HTML/CSS list box on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

The following [simple fiddle shows a list box with the set of country names](https://jsfiddle.net/RobinsonUK/e6nw2dom/).  On a PC the height property tells the page to render a list box instead of a drop-down, and consequently *n* items are visible.  On mobile (iPad/iPhone), the height property seems to tell the page how high the drop down control should be (it looks ridiculous as you'd expect).

My CSS class looks like this:

```
.sliderlist {
    width: 240px;
    height: 620px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

I would like a list box on the page, PC or mobile, not a drop-down.  How can I do this with HTML/CSS?

To clarify what I mean, the following is a photo from my iPad of what the list looks like (it's just a drop down, the height of which is given by the height property):

[image]

and on the PC with the same code we have a list box, not a drop-down.  I want this latter on mobile too:

[image]

Comment: `height: auto` why not?

Comment: I don't want a drop-down, I want a list box with n items visible.  This is the behaviour on PC in Chrome.  It isn't the behaviour in Safari on iPad and iPhone.

Comment: Yes I know, what turns the `<select>` tag into a list box is the use of the `size` attribute. There is no need for the height property at all, try: `auto`, `0`, no height at all, `vh` units like the ones proposed in the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15760589/4711865

Comment: If you want some kind of list box instead of a classic dropdown did you think about using bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns (it requires JS, though)

Comment: I added some images to clarify the difference and what I want to see.

Comment: Also why the downvote from someone?  There's an *explicit* and major difference between what I'm seeing here between two platforms.  I would have thought at the very least this is worthy of some discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that will give you results as you expect [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hulefijuxu/2/). For some unknown reason safari does not cares about the size parameter of the select option, thus we use jquery to get it done. This is the result I got on Iphone 4.

[image: result as seen on Iphone browser]

Also to get appropriate zoom levels you must include the following in the header section of the page the following code.

Try including the following line of code in head section of your page. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e6nw2dom/1/)**

```
.sliderlist {
    width: 240px;   
    height:94vh; /* newly added*/
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Nope.  It's just a very long drop-down on mobile.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I want the mobile output to look like the PC output.  That is to say, a list *box* with n items visible.  On PC there's a scrollbar.  On mobile there's no need for a scrollbar as you can swipe the list I presume.

Answer (score 1):

You can write separate class for  mobile and desktop using media query.

/*for laptop screen */

```
 @media screen 
      and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
        .sliderlist {
          width: 240px;
          height: 300px;
          font-size: 12px;
          font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
        }
    }

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
    .sliderlist {
      width: 150px;
      height: 100px;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
    }

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) { 
    .sliderlist {
      width: 240px;
      height: 300px;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
    }

}
```