# Select size on smartphone have normal dimension

Tags: html, css

in my web application I have created a select that have `size: 5`, is displayed correctly how you can see from the image:

[image]

When I open the app on mobile I get instead this dimension:

[image]

How you can see the size isn't taken correctly. I set the dimension through code and not in the css. I repeat, this is working on desktop but not in mobile, why does this happen?
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7hc6f1xL/)

**CODE:**

```
<select style='width:200px' size="5"></select>
```

Comment: Paste your html/css. And a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: Check the jsfiddle and also the code.

Comment: What devices are you using & browsers? (iOS + Safari **/** Android + Chrome?)

Comment: Nexus 5 - Android with Chrome

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760089/select-size-attribute-size-not-working-in-chrome-safari

Comment: @DenisFrezzato, the work around doesn't work for me. *(Nexus 5 with Chrome)*

Comment: @IvankaTodorova so you have the same problem?

Comment: @Sandokan, I can reproduce it. Found few questions with possible solutions, but none of them worked for me. Trying to get it working, tho. Will get back if I succeed! ^^'

Comment: Okay, thank you for the support :)

Comment: You'll find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43077503/2518317): basically, "browsers never had to respect `size` in the first place, mobile ones deliberately don't for their special UI needs"

Answer (score -1):

you have to set the media in css to allow it to open correctly in mobile device, if you are using bootstrap, it is already fit the layout of mobile. if not you have to specify it manually.

```
    @media only screen and (max-height:480px) and (orientation:portrait) { 
    .text-box
     { width: 200px; 
       size: 5;
     }
```

In your html:

```
<select class="text-box"></select>
```

Happy Coding.. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Bootstrap but this don't fit correctly on mobile, the class that I use is this: span4; there's a class also for the hight?

Comment: On size:5 I get mismatched property

Comment: try this: 
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
and tell me if it works with you, to update the answer.

Comment: But I need to use a select not a textarea.. Infact I need to replicate the size command on css

Comment: oh am sorry, try install this library, http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/, and check the example in their website.