# Size not working for SELECT OPTION in mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

While viewing on PC, the following code displays all four options. That is fine!

However, while viewing on mobile, only default option is displayed. That is actual problem.

Note: If I omit `size="4"`, then the output on PC is same as the output on mobile that is mentioned above.
It seems that `size="4"` is not working for mobile.

How to resolve this issue, please.

```css
.myClass select 
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 165px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
    <select name="mySelect" size="4">
        <option>1</option>
        <option selected>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a commom situation. Many have dealt with this issue:

- [**StackOverflow: Select size attribute size not working in Chrome/Safari?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760089/select-size-attribute-size-not-working-in-chrome-safari)
- [**StackOverflow: Select size on smartphone have normal dimension**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352318/select-size-on-smartphone-have-normal-dimension)
- [**HTMLHelp.com:  "broken" on smartphones?**](http://forums.htmlhelp.com/index.php?showtopic=19066)

Apparently this comes from the fact that browsers are not required to render the `size=""` attribute as we would expect. [**W3 specs**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-size-SELECT):

> **size = number [CN]**
>   If a SELECT element is presented as a scrolled list box, this attribute specifies the number of rows in the list that should be visible at the same time. ***Visual user agents are not required to present a SELECT element as a list box;*** they may use any other mechanism, such as a drop-down menu.
>   *(emphasys mine)*

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange, but with the values 2,3,4 size attr won't work on some devices (probably webkit browsers), it's a known bug.

You might be able to set the number of option tags manually based on mediaquery.

Comment: The result is same using values other than 2,3,4

Comment: Yea, just made a quick research. It seems that attribute "size" is ignored totally by webkit browsers. ( Try this in chrome and then in a not-webkit browser: https://jsfiddle.net/k669sm2n/ )

Comment: Size is still ignored by mobile. Is there some way other than using Select Option?

Answer (score -1):

Hm, just a blind guess, but maybe disabling `appearance` in CSS?

Ref: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/