# How to prevent <select> showing a drop down on mobile browser

Tags: html

I am trying to create a selectable list that is displayed as scrollable rather than as a drop down.

The code below works perfectly in pc/tablet browser but on a mobile devise it offers a drop down instead.

Is it possible to force the scroll option instead of the drop down on a mobile?

```
<div >
    <select name="events" id="events" data-role="none" size=25 style="width:27vw; height:50vh">
        <option>Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47xr9nt1/3/) that shows the problem (try opening in a mobile to appreciate the issue).

Alternatively if there is a better way to do it I am open to criticism/suggestions, this is my first venture into html...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is just that mobile browsers don't respect the `size` attribute of the `<select>` tag. Even desktop browsers have [historically had trouble with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760089/select-size-attribute-size-not-working-in-chrome-safari).

There's nothing you can really do about this, besides not rely on that attribute. It's not particularly difficult to create this kind of control in JavaScript. You could use a media query to decide whether to display a JavaScript version (mobile) or the `<select>` version (desktop).

```js
$('ul.select li').click(function(e){
  var item = $(e.target);
  item.addClass('selected');
  item.siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $('#events').val(item.text());
});
```

```css
ul.select {
   list-style: none;
   margin:  0;
   padding: 2px;
   border: 1px solid grey;
}

ul.select li {
   padding: 2px 6px;
}
ul.select li:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
}
ul.select li.selected {
   background-color: blue;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="events" type="hidden" name="events" value="">

<ul class="select">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

I would also note that mobile browsers deliberately display dropdown menus the way they do to improve the user experience. I'd think twice before trying to subvert that.

Comment: Thanks also for the explanation of why it is a bad idea to do what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [plugin](http://selectric.js.org/demo.html) which converts classic `select` to an html elements to customize the `select` as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I think the other answer is what I want (I tried both before deciding).