# Issue with HTML select size property

Tags: html, css

We've some cross browser issues with HTML select when we used size property. The issue is reproducible on the fiddle. In Firefox click on the select and without selecting any option click on the body area, select is fully open without applying size 1 property. When we set size 2 on blur function it's working fine. How to fix that issue with size 1?

[image]

```css
#wgtmsr{
 width:200px;  
}

#wgtmsr option{
 width:100%; 
}
```

```html
<div>
<label for="groups"style="font-size: small">Comparison Group:</label>
<select  name="wgtmsr" id="wgtmsr" onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' onmouseover='this.size=5;' onmouseout='this.size=1;'>
<option value="kg">Kg</option>
<option value="gm">Gm</option>
<option value="pound">Pound</option>
<option value="MetricTon">Metric ton</option>
<option value="litre">Litre</option>
<option value="ounce">Ounce</option>
<option value="Jamil">Jamil</option>
<option value="Ahmad">Ahmad</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: A fiddle is a great addition but in general, it's better to just post your relevant code in the question. That way, people trying to help you don't have to play around with your fiddle.

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760089/select-size-attribute-size-not-working-in-chrome-safari could help

Comment: Any update on this thread?